# Can't update cask apps using homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, file-permissions, package-managers, failed-installation

I'm using mac os catalina and I get this error when i try update my apps on homebrew

```
Phoenix@Mac ~ % brew update && brew upgrade
Already up-to-date.
==> Casks with 'auto_updates' or 'version :latest' will not be upgraded; pass `--greedy` to upgrade them.
==> Upgrading 2 outdated packages:
calibre 5.21.0 -> 5.22.1
qbittorrent 4.3.5 -> 4.3.6
==> Upgrading calibre
==> Downloading https://download.calibre-ebook.com/5.22.1/calibre-5.22.1.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/Phoenix/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c65eaf4a60a83e7d61ce123c7d199f65c2691ee721972da589027be62c9d6945--calibre-5.22.1.dmg
==> Backing App 'calibre.app' up to '/usr/local/Caskroom/calibre/5.21.0/calibre.app'
==> Removing App '/Applications/calibre.app'
==> Purging files for version 5.22.1 of Cask calibre
==> Upgrading qbittorrent
==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/qbittorrent/qbittorrent-mac/qbittorrent-4.3.6/qbittorrent-4.3.6.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/Phoenix/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/b17012b7d4e429b821b0090ee4e2b3f4e0e83afd19a19be1ee7ce5cb806ef8d9--qbittorrent-4.3.6.dmg
==> Backing App 'qBittorrent.app' up to '/usr/local/Caskroom/qbittorrent/4.3.5/qbittorrent.app'
==> Removing App '/Applications/qBittorrent.app'
==> Purging files for version 4.3.6 of Cask qbittorrent
Error: Problems with multiple casks:
calibre: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /Applications/calibre.app
qbittorrent: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /Applications/qBittorrent.app
Phoenix@Mac ~ %
```

I think the reasons is somewhat connected to my other day not be able to install the extension package on virtual box where i got this error:

```
The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: error: The owner is not root: '/Applications'.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ExtPackManagerWrap
Interface: IExtPackManager {edba9d10-45d8-b440-1712-46ac0c9bc4c5}
```

And i fixed it looking for a solution online that was to change ownership of my application folder using this command:

> sudo chown -R root:wheel /Applications

Now the mac ask me for password everytime i want to do something with my application folder and i think these 2 things are related.
Can someone help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So apparently was pretty easy to fix i just had to run:

```
sudo chown root:admin /Applications
```

And

```
sudo chmod 0775 /Applications
```

And reboot, it fixed my application folder working weirdly by asking password everytime and fixed qbittorrent installation too.
For some reason calibre still gave same error but i tried reinstalling it with

```
brew reinstall calibre
```

It gave me some errors but then asked me sudo password and it installed fine